# MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, 'Unknown error 1054')

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python, flask-mysql

1.when I'm updating I get this error

```
try:
            cur=db.cursor()
            print("update cur",cur)
            cur.execute('''UPDATE ast_details SET Asset_ID=%s,Make=%s,Model_No=%s,Serial_No=%s,
                    Purchased_Date=%s,Expired_Date=%s,Purchased_From=%s,Vendor_Name=%s,
                    Cost=%s,Laptop_Age=%s,Allocated_User=%s,
                    Allocated_Date=%s,Emp_ID=%s,Return_Date=%s where S.no=%s''',(ast_id,make,m_no,s_no,purch_dte,exp_dte,purch_frm,vndr_nme,cost,lap_age,alloc_usr,alloc_dte,emp_id,rtrn_dte,txtwhere))
        except mdb.MySQLError as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: This is not enough to answer the question, update this in except block ``from traceback import format_exc;print(format_exc())`` and provide full stack trace.

Comment: Please provide a [*reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is you question?

Answer (score 0):

```
I got solution I chnaged all column names with tild symbol it works fine for me
```

```py
cur.execute('''UPDATE `ast_details` SET `Asset_ID`=%s,`Make`=%s,`Model_No`=%s,`Serial_No`=%s,
                    `Purchased_Date`=%s,`Expired_Date`=%s,`Purchased_From`=%s,`Vendor_Name`=%s,
                    `Cost`=%s,`Laptop_Age`=%s,`Allocated_User`=%s,
                    `Allocated_Date`=%s,`Emp_ID`=%s,`Return_Date`=%s WHERE `S.no`=%s''',(ast_id,make,m_no,s_no,purch_dte,exp_dte,purch_frm,vndr_nme,cost,lap_age,alloc_usr,alloc_dte,emp_id,rtrn_dte,txtwhere,))
```